# error: cannot find symbol class MarginLayoutParams

Tags: android

I downloaded Telegram source code. It worked very very good but suddenly i saw this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol class MarginLayoutParams
```

I import all library that was need but my issue did not solve.A part of my code is:

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
 import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.FocusFinder;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.VelocityTracker;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.widget.EdgeEffect;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

   public static class LayoutParams extends MarginLayoutParams {
    ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    final Rect mDecorInsets = new Rect();
    boolean mInsetsDirty = true;
    boolean mPendingInvalidate = false;
    public LayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);
    }
    }
```

Comment: can you show more code, how you import library, etc

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html

Comment: @CommonsWare, I saw this site but did not solve my problem.